# Manipulating array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have got an array like this:

```
A = {{{1, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 15}}, {{5, 6, 9}, {7, 8, 2}}, {{9, 10, 
1}, {11, 12, 3}}}
```

I make differences in each sublist a following way

```
Dif = Differences[A, {0, 0, 1}]
```

and get

```
 {{{3, 1}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 3}, {1, -6}}, {{1, -9}, {1, -9}}}
```

Then I want to duplicate the first difference in each sublist, which means I would like to obtain array like this:

```
 {{{3, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 8}}, {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, -6}}, {{1, 1, -9}, {1, 1, -9}}}
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Is there any function which would help?

Comment: `list[[All, All, {1,1,2}]] `?

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the content of the initial comment:

```
list = {{{3, 1}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 3}, {1, -6}}, {{1, -9}, {1, -9}}};
list[[All, All, {1, 1, 2}]]

(*{{{3, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 8}}, {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, -6}}, {{1, 1, -9}, {1, 
   1, -9}}}*)
```

For those of the code golf or one-liner persuasion, you can save a whopping two characters by:

```
list[[;; , ;; , {1, 1, 2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to duplicate the first difference in each sublist,

```
a = {{{1, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 15}}, {{5, 6, 9}, {7, 8, 2}}, {{9, 10, 1}, {11, 12, 3}}}
dif = Differences[a, {0, 0, 1}]

(* {{{3, 1}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 3}, {1, -6}}, {{1, -9}, {1, -9}}} *)

Cases[#, {x_, y_} :> {x, x, y}] & /@ dif
(*{{{3, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 8}}, {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, -6}}, {{1, 1, -9}, {1, 1, -9}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aA = {{{1, 4, 5}, {3, 7, 15}}, {{5, 6, 9}, {7, 8, 2}}, {{9, 10, 1}, {11, 12, 3}}};
dif = Differences[aA, {0, 0, 1}];
(* {{{3, 1}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 3}, {1, -6}}, {{1, -9}, {1, -9}}} *)
```

My favorite being `dif[[All,All,{1,1,2}]]` suggested by @Yves in comments, you can also use

```
Map[ArrayPad[#, {1, 0}, "Fixed"] &, dif, {-2}]
(* {{{3,3,1},{4,4,8}},{{1,1,3},{1,1,-6}},{{1,1,-9},{1,1,-9}}} *)

MapAt[Sequence @@ {#, ##} &, dif, {All, All, 1}]
(* {{{3,3,1},{4,4,8}},{{1,1,3},{1,1,-6}},{{1,1,-9},{1,1,-9}}} *)
```